# How can i pass a JSON array from php to JS?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, morris.js

im trying to populate a morris.js chart from a set of results. In my controller I create an array of the results and use json_encode to create a json array, here is the output in my view using print_r:

```
{"Positive":7,"Negative":26,"Pending":786,"Contact the Clinic":242,"Misc":2}
```

How would I pass this to my morris.js chart to populate the chart using this data as label / value pairs? everything I try I get either a blank chart or an "undefined" variable or "NaN". Here is my controller:

```
function execute_search()
{
    // Retrieve the posted search term.
    $search_term = $this->input->post('search');

    // Get results count and pass it as json:
    $data = $this->search_model->count_res('$p_results_data');
    $pos = 0; $neg= 0; $pen = 0; $cont = 0; $misc = 0;
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['result'] === 'Positive') {
            $pos++;
        } elseif ($item['result'] === 'Negative') {
            $neg++;
        } elseif ($item['result'] === 'Pending') {
            $pen++;
        } elseif ($item['result'] === 'Contact the Clinic') {
            $cont++;
        } else {
            $misc++;
        }
    }
    $res = array("Positive"=>$pos, "Negative"=>$neg, "Pending"=>$pen, "Contact the Clinic"=>$cont, "Misc"=>$misc);
    $data = json_encode($res);

    // Use the model to retrieve results:
    $this->data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_results($search_term);
    $this->data['chart'] = $data;
    $this->data['totals'] = $this->search_model->total_res('$total_res');

    // Pass the results to the view.
    $this->data['subview'] = ('user/search_results');
    $this->load->view('_layout_admin', $this->data);
}
```

and my morris.js:

```
$results = "<?php echo $chart ?>";
new Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donutEg',
    data: [
        $results
    ],
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you loading your `morris.js`? If you do it with a script tag in HTML, the file is not parsed by the php server.

Comment: <?php echo json_encode($chart) ?>

Comment: my script is loaded in my page footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, JSON.parse is your friend, assuming you have JSON that was created by PHP's json_encode function:

```
$results = "<?php echo $chart ?>";
new Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donutEg',
    data: [
        JSON.parse( $results )
    ],
});
```

OR POSSIBLY

```
$results = "<?php echo $chart ?>";
new Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donutEg',
    data: JSON.parse( $results )
});
```

BUT THE WAY I DO IT

In the view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="chartData" value='<?php echo $chart; ?>' />
```

In the JS (using jQuery):

```
var chartData = $('#chartData').val();
new Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donutEg',
    data: JSON.parse( chartData )
});
```

After looking at the documentation for morris.js, I found that this is how you can do it the right way:

```
// Looking at the docs for morris.js:
// http://jsbin.com/ukaxod/144/embed?js,output

// This is your data, but it's all in one json object
var chartData = JSON.parse( $('#chartData').val() );

// We need to break up that object into parts of the donut
var donutParts = [];
$.each( chartData, function(k,v){
    donutParts.push({
        label: k,
        value: v
    });
});

// Now create the donut
Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donutEg',
    data: donutParts
});
```

Comment: Tried all 3 with no luck :( been stuck on this all day! Thanks for trying tho

Comment: Don't be stuck. If you want your question answered, what kind of error are you getting? What are you expecting? I don't know about the others, but I'm not a mind reader. I'm not sure what you are expecting {data} to be. If you want data to include a js object that was the contents of your json encoded chart data, that's what I'm trying to do for you.

Comment: sorry, im passing a set of results as an array and I need to convert the array into label:value pairs. eg Label: "Positive", Value: 7 but everything ive tried either results in no graph being shown or I get a label with a Not a Number (NaN) value, (very little experience with javascript), im not getting any errors. Thank you for your help, it is very much appreciated

Comment: In my last example, as long as you use single quotes for the value attribute of the hidden input, you should see your json string in that value when you look at the page source. Are you using jQuery? If you are, and you use my last example, then the value of data is a js object, and inside your Donut method you would find the value of "Positive" by using param.data.Positive. Your Donut method needs a parameter, so if the Donut method signature looks like Donut( x ), then "Positive" would be x.data.Positive. If it's not, then try using console.log(x) and tell me what is in your console.

Comment: Good Morning, Using your last example the data is there in the hidden div but still no chart being shown, I get this error on the console: "Syntax error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data" my results are coming from an SQL query in my search model. Thanks again

** Update **
Got rid of that error, im now getting no errors in the console log but also no chart being displayed

Comment: secondly will it be affected if i load my script in a seperate file in my footer? I think a course on javascript and jquery is now on the horizon

Comment: I revised my answer after looking at the morris.js docs. Should now qualify as the accepted answer.

Comment: Tried again with no joys, I still get a blank div where the chart should be displayed, I think the graphs re very 'fragile', IE they don't like anything other than static data, I've tried loading them in an external script file, i've tried the script directly in the footer, I've tried passing $chart as an indexed array and a JSON array, he console still shows no errors. Could you recommend a different chart library possibly? Cheers.

Comment: I appear to have it working with your revised answer, for some reason if I use this in a seperate JS file that i named chart.js and load this in my footer its working great and results are being populated via my database searches. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `morris.js` is a normal javascript file, you cannot use php there by default: The server will not parse the `.js` file so the php source code will appear in your javascript.

You need to either:

- Put the `morris.js` script contents in a php page in a javascript block so that the php gets parsed;
- Make an ajax request from your `morris.js` script to get the data from the server in a separate request;
- Set up your server to parse `.js` files as if they are / contain php.

The last one is just to illustrate what you would need, I would not recommend doing that.

Comment: An alternative is using an embedded script tag in the php file to only populate a global variable that can be used later in the `morris.js` file, That's what I would probably use.

Comment: @xander You're right, that's what I would probably do as well but I don't know `morris.js` so to avoid loading one before the other, leading to new problems, I didn't mention it. And it's only a few lines :-)

Comment: How would I go about the AJAX request? im a bit of a noob as ive been out of the field for around 9 years! thanks

Comment: @jeroen
is it possible to "clip" the label string to 3 characters in your answer? for example I want the label to be a max of 3 charachters for certain graphs? is this possible? eg:
"Positive" would become "Pos"? Cheers